# How to make the Div expand to fit the screen vertically when in portrait mode

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and the body expands depending on the length of the screen size, but i cannot get the DIV to expand to 100%.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>xxxx</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jqtouch/jqtouch.min.js" type="application/x-javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="carousel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="mousewheel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">       
            $(function() {
                $(".anyClass").jCarouselLite({
                    btnNext: ".next",
                    btnPrev: ".prev"
                });
                $(".mouseWheel .jCarouselLite").jCarouselLite({
                    mouseWheel: true
                });
        });</script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: black; background-size: 100% 100% height: 100%; min-height: 100%;">

        <div id="wrapper" style="width: 80%; margin-left: 10%; background-image: url(http://happps.com/marketing/dgblur.jpg);  background-size: 100% 100%; height: 100%;">
            ttttt
        </div> <!--wrapper-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a style attribute in your <html> tag. I'd suggest removing that

Comment: thanks i took that out, but still the div doesnt expand

Comment: or i should say doesnt fit the whole screen if the screen is long whereas the body does adjust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - don't use inline css

Second - use meta:

Third - set css media queries to change width to change styles for portrait mode:

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* Portrait styles */
}
```

EDIT:

oh okay, set html and body height to 100%, then add div height to 100%. that should help

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: the problem is not the width if you read the question.  its the height.  The width is fine.